# How to simplify the following constraints as I'm using MIP optimization solver in python?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, convex-optimization

Following is the initial snippet of the code:

```
# o is the model and x,y are variables and a,w are parameters. (i=1,...p and j=1,...n and k=1,....r) 

# ( X_ij,  Y_kj,  W_k,   A_ik)

(o += w[0] *(y[0][0] + y[0][1]) >= xsum (a[i][0]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][0]* x[i][1] for i in p)

o += w[1] *(y[1][0] + y[1][1]) >= xsum (a[i][1]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][1]* x[i][1] for i in p) 

o += w[2] *(y[2][0] + y[2][1]) >= xsum (a[i][2]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][2]* x[i][1] for i in p)
#..

#..upto r times

o += w[0] *(y[0][0] + y[0][1] + y[0][2]) >= xsum (a[i][0]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][0]* x[i][1] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][0]* x[i][2] for i in p)

o += w[1] *(y[1][0] + y[1][1] + y[1][2]) >= xsum (a[i][1]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][1]* x[i][1] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][1]* x[i][2] for i in p)

o += w[2] *(y[2][0] + y[2][1] + y[2][2]) >= xsum (a[i][2]* x[i][0] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][2]* x[i][1] for i in p) + xsum (a[i][2]* x[i][2] for i in p)
```

I simplified the above to the following which is correct

```
for k in r:

    o += (w[k] * y[k][0]) >= xsum (a[i][k]* x[i][0] for i in p)
for k in r:

    o += (w[k] * (y[k][0]+ y[k][1])) >= xsum (a[i][k]* x[i][1] for i in p)
```

But i need to simplify further, so, how to simplify further?

I tried this:

```
for j in n:

    for k in r:

        o += xsum(w[k] *y[k][j] for j in n) >= xsum (a[i][k]* x[i][j] for i in p)
```

But it is not correct representation as I got wrong answers.

( Though I didn't explained in detail, hope this might be enough for my issue with simplification of constraints, please reply if needed more details)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with the mathematical model. Code is harder to read, and it is better to figure out first if this is a modeling issue, or an implementation issue.

Comment: Thank you much @Kuifje  for suggestion and the response form Walter Sebastian Gilser solves my issue with coding simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear and isn't really an OR question, but I think what you are trying to do is the following:

```
for j in n:
    for k in r:
        o += xsum(w[k] *y[k][jj] for jj in n if jj <= j) >= xsum (a[i][k]* x[i][j] for i in p)
```

Comment: Yes, this solves my requirement. Thank you very much for timely response.